# How to call apex class from force.com sites

Tags: apex, rest-api, force.com-sites

I have rest resource class which i am calling from force.com site..

Below is my site url

http://partial-sms.cs31.force.com/webhook

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/webhook/*')

global  without sharing class smsSiteAPI {
   @HttpGet
    global static ID getUrlParameters(){

        Id urlId = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id');

        system.debug('Url id '+urlId);

        return urlID;
    }

}
```

And below is the Active Site Home Page

```
<apex:page controller="smsSiteAPI">
    <apex:outputText value="{!UrlParameters}" />
</apex:page>
```

when i hit url "https://partial-sms.cs31.force.com/webhook?id=1234" it gives error:
"Authorization Required You must first log in or register before accessing this page.
If you have forgotten your password, click Forgot Password to reset it."

[image: I already have permission to the class smsSiteAPI]

Comment: Have you granted access to the class to the site guest user?

Comment: Yes i granted access to the class to the site guest user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to grant the APEX class access to the site profile.
Please find below format for calling the API from the site.

```
https://<site-url>/services/apexrest/<your-web-service-name>
```

If the class is part of the managed package, then you need to include the package namespace as well.

```
https://<site-url>/services/apexrest/<namespace>/<your-web-service-name>
```

With the above-mentioned format it working, see!

[image]

Comment: Thanks Rahul! but why it is showing is under construction? Why not i am able to see output at developer console? Please help me, I am new to such scenario.

Comment: @jsmith - you need to set debug log traces for the site guest user to see debug output; not for you, the developer